# "make:entity --regenerate" creates an incorrect (?) function

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine, symfony4

I'm currently following a Symfony tutorial, and I've gotten to the part of Doctrine bidirectional relations (sorry if the terms I'm using are wrong, I'm not an native English speaker). My model is based on an Advert (One-To-Many) that displays an array of Applications (Many-To-One) made to this Advert. So an Application has to be linked to an Advert, hence the `nullable false` :

```
class Application
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Advert", inversedBy="applications")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $advert;

    //
}
```

And I added an `$applications` attribute to my Advert class:

```
class Advert
{ 
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Application", mappedBy="advert")
     */
    private $applications;

    //
}
```

But when I use `php bin/console make:entity --regenerate`, to get the `removeApplication()` function, the code I'm getting is the following:

```
public function removeApplication(Application $application): self
{
    if ($this->applications->contains($application)) {
        $this->applications->removeElement($application);
        // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
        if ($application->getAdvert() === $this) {
            $application->setAdvert(null);
        }
    }

    return $this;
}
```

The function sets the `$advert` of the Application to null while this attribute is explicitly set to `nullable = false`. I noticed this inconsistency because I'm using Symfony 4 whereas the tutorial I'm following is based on an older version, so the functions generated in the tutorial were much simpler and did not handle the `$advert` attribute.

Any idea why this is happening and if it might cause an error later in my project? Let me know if you need more pieces of code to understand the problem.

Comment: It looks like a bug to me. You should create an issue on github : https://github.com/symfony/maker-bundle/issues/new

Answer (score 0):

That really looks like a bug to me, they probably do not handle nullable cases inside of the generator.

Maybe try orphanRemoval on the Advert side of the relation, would be interesting what would happen then:

```
class Advert
{ 
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Application", mappedBy="advert", orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $applications;
}
```

Comment: Regenerating with orphanRemoval set to true outputs the exact same removeApplication() function

Comment: Ok then they really did not take that case in mind when creating the generator.

Comment: I'm still waiting for an answer to the issue I created on Github but yeah this is probably what happened